# What would the output of this ADC be?

Tags: adc

I've never used a bipolar ADC before, so I have a pretty easy question about it. I've skimmed over the datasheet and some references to Vref, but not enough to explain what my output codes are.

I'm looking at the [ADS1282 ADC](http://www.ti.com/product/ads1282) and I can set Vref (REFPx and REFNx pins) to essentially whatever I want within the limits of my supply.

For the purpose of understanding what happens, neglect any common mode input range, gain and other stuff. Lets say, I have an 8bit ADC +/- 2.5V bipolar supply with a Vref of 2V. If my input is 1V, what is my output ? If my input is -1V, what is my output ?

Would it be +128 for Vin=1 and -127 for Vin=-1 ?

Comment: yes, it sounds like it

Answer (score 2):

It no longer makes sense to say `Vref = 2V` in a bipolar single-ended ADC.  You now have `Vref-`, which is converted as full-scale low, and `Vref+`, which is converted to full-scale high.  Inputs between your *two* reference inputs will be linear (within the linearity error), and inputs beyond either of the references will either be clipped or destroy the device (depending on whether you respect the maximum ratings).  This is sometimes called pseudo-differential, because it is the same as subtracting the negative reference from all other analog inputs.

However, the ADS1282 would be better described as fully differential.  In this case the inputs are not limited to the range determined by the references; a common-mode signal may exist which will be cancelled as long as the input range determined by the power supplies is not exceeded.  And it does not make any sense to talk about an input of `+1V`, or `-1V`.  You have *two* inputs per channel, and the difference and common-mode offset are both important.

In the context of the power supply, an ADC supporting bipolar supplies simply means that AVSS is not tied to DVSS.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between Vref and the full-scale input range depends on the specific chip. The datasheet you linked to is for a 24-bit delta-sigma ADC, but then you ask about a hypothetical 8-bit ADC.

For the ADS1282, Table 3 in the datasheet gives the relationship: As long as the PGA is set to unity gain, the full-scale input range runs from -Vref/2 to + Vref/2.